# Updating TimeToLiveSpecification for DynamoDB using CloudFormation

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-cloudformation

I've deployed DynamoDB table using CloudFormation like this:

```
  exampleTable:
    Type: AWS::DynamoDB::Table
    Properties:
      BillingMode: PAY_PER_REQUEST
      KeySchema:
        - AttributeName: id
          KeyType: HASH
        - AttributeName: prop
          KeyType: RANGE
      TimeToLiveSpecification:
        AttributeName: foo
        Enabled: true
```

Changeing TTL attribute to `bar` successfully deployed, but changes does not reflect to dashboard.

https://docs.amazonaws.cn/en_us/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/time-to-live-ttl-before-you-start.html#time-to-live-ttl-before-you-start-notes
says

> You cannot reconfigure TTL to look for a different attribute. You must disable TTL, and then reenable TTL with the new attribute going forward.

Do I need to deploy 2 times even when using CloudFormation?
(once for disabling TTL and once for enabling TTL with new attribute name)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Do I need to deploy 2 times even when using CloudFormation?

Yes. The fact that you have to disable it first is explicitly stated in CloudFormation docs for [AttributeName](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-dynamodb-timetolivespecification.html):

> To update this property, you **must first disable TTL** then enable TTL with the new attribute name.